# Ubuntu 17.04 - Changed hostname, now my bitcoin core won't work

Tags: command-line, 17.04, bitcoin

I believe this occurred after I tried to change the name of my computer since it was a default and had a bunch of numbers after it.

After changing it, I started to experience weird things with my `sudo` command, such as my password failing multiple times.  A reboot ended up fixing that.

Now I am trying to run my `bitcoin-core` using `bitcoin-qt` in the terminal.

It gives me this error:

> bitcoin-qt: symbol lookup error: bitcoin-qt: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN12QApplication10commitDataER15QSessionManager

I've tried to uninstall using --purge and reinstall.  I've deleted the folder in `/usr/bin/bitcoin-qt` and tried running it from that folder itself but still wouldn't work.

I'm not sure if there is a config file somewhere else that it uses but I've tried just about everything short of a complete OS reinstallation and  nothing will work.

I did change my hostname in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` and even tried to change it back to what it originally was which was like "xxx-GL551JK" but my bitcoin core refuses to open.

I've tried running just the program itself too from the Search menu and that doesn't work either.

**Edit 1**: I just reinstalled a fresh copy of Ubuntu and the same error popped up. I literally had this thing running yesterday. I'm already pretty tired of Ubuntu. Almost nothing works out of box.

**Edit 2**:  I just did a second reinstall while overwriting the entire SSD and installed it just the way I did the first time and it's all working again.

**Edit 3**:  I've reinstalled this system I don't know how many times.  Every time I reset my computer after downloading the Core, it gives me this lookup error.  Literally have reinstalled 4 times and every time it occurs after restarting my computer.  I've closed the application and even `sudo killall bitcoin-qt` every time I tried to log off and then it inevitably gives me this same symbol lookup error. I've even tried 2 different versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you bother to find out how changing a hostname would affect your bitcoin app before doing so, and how long have you been using Ubuntu?

Comment: Why should changing my name on a computer that gives me a UI to change my name affect anything?  It's like offering a button to blow up your system in a folder on the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I'm on a 64 bit installation of Ubuntu 16.04.

I went to /usr/local/lib and found all my QtCore/QtGui/QtNetwork files there.  I moved them all to /usr/.

Now I can run Bitcoin-qt again fine.

I have no idea why it breaks or why it cannot seem to run after the initial boot up or why this fixes it but it seems to work.

Note:  There are many libQtCore/Gui/Network files for many different programs but it seems Bitcoin-qt uses the ones in /usr/local/lib and it breaks for some reason whenever you restart the computer.  Moving them fixed it for me but only moving the ones in /usr/local/lib and all of them.